# Assigning a row range to a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying so hard. I cant figure this out. I am working with two sheets. One sheet searches for a criteria "RR", ir there is an RR, it assigns a variable a serial to be searched in another sheet. If the serial is found in the other sheet, I would like to determine the row where it is located and assign it to a variable. "DidTransfer = Sheets(PreviousTabName).Range("B" & thiscell.Row).Value" The problem when I use thiscell.Row, its giving me so many problems. I need the row number to so I can reference the same row to get information from another cell on the same row. Please help.

```
Sub TempModifier()

Dim NYSID, PLookUpTabRange, IsRR, DidTransfer As String

Dim thiscell As Range

'Variable for Temp
Dim TempFirstRow As Integer
Dim TempLastRow As Long

'Variables for the previous
Dim PreviousTabLastRow As Long
Dim PreviousTabFirstRow As Integer

'Initialize the temp variables
TempLastRow = Sheets("Temp").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

PreviousTabName = "February"
PreviousTabFirstRow = 7

With Sheets(PreviousTabName)
        PreviousTabLastRow = .Cells(256, "H").End(xlUp).Row 'Get the last row in the data range
End With

'Create a data-range variable
PLookUpTabRange = "H" & PreviousTabFirstRow & ":" & "H" & PreviousTabLastRow

'Begin looping structure to copy data from the temp tab to the current tab



For TempFirstRow = 2 To TempLastRow

    'Assign the value of the housing unit
    IsRR = Sheets("Temp").Cells(TempFirstRow, 2).Value

    'Check if the value is RR
    If IsRR = "RR        " Then
        'If the value is RR, then get the NYSID
        NYSID = Worksheets("Temp").Cells(TempFirstRow, 4).Value

        If Not IsError(Application.Match(NYSID, Worksheets(PreviousTabName).Range(PLookUpTabRange), 0)) Then

        'NYSID is Found on Current Month Sheet, do Nothing

        Else

            DidTransfer = ""
            Set thiscell = Sheets(PreviousTabName).Columns("D").Find(What:=NYSID, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

                DidTransfer = Sheets(PreviousTabName).Range("B" & thiscell.Row).Value

                    Select Case DidTransfer

                        Case "Transferred"
                            DidTransfer = "Transferred"
                        Case Else
                            DidTransfer = DidTransfer

                    End Select

            If IsError(Application.Match(NYSID, Worksheets(PreviousTabName).Range(PLookUpTabRange), 0)) Or _
            (Not IsError(Application.Match(NYSID, Worksheets(PreviousTabName).Range(PLookUpTabRange), 0)) And _
                 DidTransfer = "Transferred") Then

                    'Worksheets("Temp").Rows(TempFirstRow).Delete
                    MsgBox "Delete"

            End If

        End If

    End If



'Go to the next row
Next TempFirstRow



End Sub
```

Comment: There are a lot of things *wrong* with this code - I'll try to keep this short. `Dim NYSID, PLookUpTabRange, IsRR, DidTransfer As String` is only declaring `DidTransfer` as string, the rest are variants. Make all your integers long. Put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module. Why are you looking for `RR          `? Use `Trim` instead. If you're deleting rows, you need to loop backwards (using `Step -1`) or you're going to encounter issues. There are more, but you should cut your question down to something more tangible so that we can help you...

Comment: `DidTransfer = DidTransfer` is useless. `.Cells(256, "H").End(xlUp).Row` - why 256? This isn't always going to give you the right value, depending on your data set. Your `IsError` snippet at the bottom looks like it's saying "Whether it's an error or not, do this anyways", which makes no sense... I'm not trying to be  mean when I say this, but I genuinely think you should start over and really think about what you're trying to accomplish - keep it simple!

Comment: If you are going to delete rows then `For TempFirstRow = 2 To TempLastRow` is going to be `For TempFirstRow = TempLastRow To 2 step -1`

Comment: They're saying when you delete a row, the next one is skipped as the `xlShftUp` moved the next up to the current iteration. You can either `Step - 1`, or have your iteration minus 1 -- `TempFirstRow = TempFirstRow  - 1` to not skip your rows.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. Made the modifications as needed. I need some clarification. Dwirony the Referenced table (256) if the last row with the data of interest. After 256, there is other data that I would like not to include. Erjon, can you clarify more as to how I would structure the loop? Is is just as simple as modifying the loop code that I have and replacing it with the code you have?